# Cannot view values for the fields in Hibernate Query Fetch on GAE

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jsf-2

Cannot view values for the fields in Hibernate Query Fetch on GAE.

```
Query query  = session.createSQLQuery("select s.id,e.firstName, e.middleName, e.lastName, es.title as empStatusTitle,e.transportMode as trModeId," +
        " tr.title as trMode" +
        " from SecurityPrincipals as s " +
        " left join Employee as e on e.userId=s.id " +                  
        " left join EmployeeStatus as es on e.employeeStatus = es.id " +        
        " left join TransportationModes as tr on e.transportMode = tr.id " +                    
        " where s.id= :userId").setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(EmployeeDTO.class));

query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

When I call employeeDTO.getTrMode(),employeeDTO.getEmpStatusTitle got all values correctly and running properly in local machine.But when I try to deploy on  GAE the value is not getting in the view.jsf but it is there when running locally.I have getters and setters for all these in EmployeeDTO.java. All others like firstName,middleName,lastName has no problem.

My employeeView.jsf is :

```
<h:outputText value="Transport Mode" />
<h:outputText id="transportMode" value="#{employeeView.employeeDTO.trMode}" style="font-weight:bold" />

<h:outputText value="Employee Status" />
<h:outputText id="employeeStatus" value="#{employeeView.employeeDTO.empStatusTitle}" style="font-weight:bold" />
```

Comment: Well, do you hava the same data in your local database and in the GAE database? What happens if you log the values of the DTO? Do they appear in the log? If so, it would be a problm with your JSF code.

Comment: When I tried to print the values `System.out.println("EMPLOYEE STATUS: CURRENT : "+employeeDTO.getEmployeeStatusdto()+employeeDTO.getEmpStatusTitle());` , at very first time it is getting 0,null respectively. But on running further again getting original values. Why it is so happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it all works locally, then your code and query are probably fine. And since it does not work on GAE, then there is probably something environmental that's different. The database is different or not configured properly. You should put some error checking code in to make sure the query is actually working.

Comment: Actually the values are therein Database and I think the configuration is correct. When I tried to print the values `System.out.println("EMPLOYEE STATUS: CURRENT : "+employeeDTO.getEmployeeStatusdto()+employeeDTO.getEmpStatusTitle());` , at very first time it is getting 0,null respectively. But on running further again getting original values. Why it is so happening?

Comment: I would turn on log4j DEBUG tracing in Hibernate to see what it's actually doing and what the database is returning.